# How do I deal with the problem of stale cookies breaking logins on a migrated site?

Tags: cookies

I just finished the migration of a D7 site into D9.

Unfortunately, as I kept the same domain, before the first time I login to the new D9 site, I have to remove my domain's cookies from within my browser. If I don't remove the cookies, I can't login. (I assume there is some kind of conflict between the D7 cookies and the D9 login process)

My idea is to create a form with a submit button which will remove the D7 cookies.

Here is my code:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $cookies = \Drupal::request()->cookies;
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
      setcookie($cookie, "", time() - 3600);
    }
  }
```

I am not sure If I need to remove all cookies... which one should be deleted?
Also, this code fail because some cookie name have coma like `eF8gbELtR4DO6pRrsjgk1J,XFZlXH83j28-5ssIcvBPz,zsw`

Comment: This is a known bug https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2868384

Comment: Many thanks!!!! you saved my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2868384) when migrating from Drupal 7. Use one of the patches on that issue. In the current form these patches work by introducing an optional `session_suffix` session service configuration. By configuring that value in services.yml with a short string you will effectively invalidate all session cookies.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have patched the core files (#56 for 9.5) but the reset password process lead to an access denied page. Removing the cookies solve this issue. I am back to my original question: I would like to create a form which remove the cookies (to avoid to explain to all users how to do it)

Comment: Thanks to your help, I could make it work by adding the `session_suffix` key in my `services.yml` file. This key should be present in the `default.services.yml` file after you have applied the patch. You can copy it in your own `services.yml` file and add a value for it. It could be nice to add this explanation in your answerr...